# Optimize EAN-13 to be Displayed on Cell Phones

Tags: ios, image-processing, signal-processing, barcode

I'm currently working on a project with a client, the goal is to enable his clients to be able to receive `EAN-13` barcodes via custom app/email and use them to get instant discounts on self-checkout machines (SACAT) at his store.

Basically the clients walks to the machine, scans his products and at the end scans the barcode sent to his cellphone in order to get the discount.

We've been trying some prototypes but it's very hard to get the laser barcode reader on the machine to read a barcode displayed in a cellphone screen. We've tried multiple heigh/size factors on the bar codes but it just doesn't work the same way as a normal printed barcode.

How can we tweak the barcode to make it easier to read on a cellphone screen?

Comment: please provide more specifics.

Comment: @DanielA.White I explained the process, we email the barcode to the client and he scans it on the self-checkout machine.

Comment: ok so how is that generated? can you use a different barcode type?

Comment: @DanielA.White it must be `EAN-13` because it's the same as all the other products on the store. The machines can't read other types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't, or perhaps more accurately you may want to look at non-laser based reader devices or other delivery mechanism.

Self-checkout machines using a laser expect that the barcode is printed on paper or plastic with similar reflectivity properties. It is the difference in specular reflection between the white and black lines that determine an edge along with how long did it take to get to the next edge which makes up a 'bar' in barcode.

My guess is that laser receiver/sensor when faced with a modern cellphone screen which could be made of glass or plastic sees nothing if you showed an image of barcode. The LCD image doesn't interact with the laser in any meaningful way.

Any barcode scanner unit which could handle a cellphone screen would probably be image based. Once you have the image its pretty straight forward to decode the image, i.e. ZXing.

If you are wondering why image processing isn't used more at self-checkout, if you are using a 1D code, lasers are more tolerant of size (more focusable range), lighting conditions (provide own source) and object position (typically a set of scan lines in various orientations) and has been around for a long time (mid to late 1970s). If you are using a 2D code then your reader most likely will have some image processing (camera) based technology.